# How to insert data to table by store procedure with auto-incremented column

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as below

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS maintain//    
CREATE PROCEDURE maintain 
(    
    IN inMaintainType   CHAR(1),    -- 'i' = Insert, 'u'= Update/Edit, 'd'= Delete 
    IN inEntityId       INT,            -- 0 for Insert Case
    IN inEntityName     VARCHAR(100),
    IN inEntityDescription  VARCHAR(100),
    IN inEntityPrefix   CHAR(1),
    IN inStatus     CHAR(1),    -- 'a' = Active, 'i' = Not active
    IN inEmpId      INT,
    OUT outReturnStatus     INT,
    OUT outReturnRemarks    VARCHAR(100)
)

BEGIN    
    IF inMaintainType= 'i'
    THEN
        INSERT INTO Entity
        (
            EntityId,
            EntityName,
            EntityDescription,
            EntityPrefix,
            Status,
            CreatedBy,
            CreatedDate,
            ModifiedBy,
            ModifiedDate
        ) 
        VALUES
        (
            li_EntityId,
            inEntityName,
            inEntityDescription,
            inEntityPrefix,  
            'a',
            inEmpId,
            now(),
            inEmpId,
            now()
        );

        if row_count() != 0
            THEN SET outReturnStatus =0 ,
                outReturnRemarks = 'Insert Successful';
            ELSE SET outReturnStatus = 1,
                outReturnRemarks = 'Insert Not Successful';  
            END IF;                     
        END IF ;
```

I want to call the procedure to insert data with variables

```
mysql_query("CALL maintain('i','$EntityId','$EntityName','$EntityDescription','$EntityPrefix','$Status','$EmpId',@outvari1,@outvari2)")or die(mysql_error());
```

But it's showing me the error

> Unknown column 'li_EntityId' in 'field list'

EntityId is the auto incremented field.

Comment: Is this because li_EntityID doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in the above SP apart from where it is inserted into the table.  Where should the value of li_EntityId be coming from?

Comment: in the table  EntityId is set as AI, so li_EntityId is the auto-incremented value

Comment: So why are you attempting to insert a value to an Auto-Incremented field - surely the table will handle that for you and assign a value for the record at execution time?

Comment: If i remove the value from my query like: mysql_query("CALL p_maintain_entity('i','newaddition','newaddition','N','$Status','1',@outvari1,@outvari2)")or die(mysql_error()); It shows the error : Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE databasename.p_maintain_entity; expected 9, got 8

Comment: And if you remove the EntityId from the INSERT INTO statement...?

Comment: It's saying "Missing value in the form"

Comment: Yes, It worked. I remove EntityId from insert into statement as well as its value li_EntityID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95350/discussion-between-jonnus-and-user3518270).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the comments above into an actual answer...

You have set up your table so that the field EntityId will Auto-Increment.

Because of this when you insert a record into the table you don't need to explicitly add a value for the ID field - it will do it for you.

The solution is therefore to remove the EntityId field from the INSERT INTO ... statement, and to remove the li_EntityId value from the inserted values, so only 8 arguments are passed into the remaining 8 fields.